Fire enqueue function Wordpress
Is it possible to fire an enqueue function in Wordpress?
In the functions.php file I added the function below
function classicStyles() {
    if ( ! wp_theme_has_theme_json() ) {
        $suffix = wp_scripts_get_suffix();
        wp_register_style( 'classic-theme-styles', '/' . WPINC . "/css/classic-themes$suffix.css" );
        wp_style_add_data( 'classic-theme-styles', 'path', ABSPATH . WPINC . "/css/classic-themes$suffix.css" );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'classic-theme-styles' );
    }
}

add_action('onlyClassic', 'classicStyles');

In the header file I use
do_action('onlyClassic');

The code returns empty / nothing
I do not use wp_head(); so I looking for a solution to run/fire this function.
Who can help me?

the wp_head() is where the script tags are rendered, so you have to provide an alternative rendering eg there is a wp_print_head_scripts function and wp_print_footer_scripts which is invoked by the wp_head function
